# Where can i find complete API reference of nlp_architect by Intel AI Lab

Tags: nlp

I have started exploring NLP and came across `nlp_architect`, which exactly caters my needs, but their website seems to be void of any proper API reference, what I found is [API reference](http://nlp_architect.nervanasys.com/api.html), but this only provides for models and datasets. I have been following [this tutorial](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/nlp-architect/blob/master/tutorials/intent_extraction/intent_extraction_demo.ipynb) and it uses imports like `nlp_architect.utils` but I can't find any documentations related to it.

Does anyone knows about some helpful links that provides complete API reference of `nlp-architect`

Answer (score 0):

NLP Architect is in active development and our documentation is being updated in each version. Please see our github repo for further info.

`nlp_architect.utils` package contains a lot of useful utilities to work with the library and also with textual data:

- `nlp_architect.utils.embedding` contains methods for loading pre-trained word embedding models, such as GloVE/Fasttext (from downloaded files) or ELMo.
- `nlp_architect.utils.generic` contains generic utils, such as, one-hot encoding of tensors, sequence padding, etc.
- `nlp_architect.utils.io` contains IO related methods such as downloading files, validating input, paths, parsing files, etc.
- `nlp_architect.utils.metrics` contains CoNLL eval type metric that is used in sequential labeling tasks.
- `nlp_architect.utils.string` contains string normalization and processing utilities.
- `nlp_architect.utils.text` contains textual processing related methods such as for generating a vocabulary, generating tensors from arrays of sentences or words, tokenizer, sentence normalizer, etc.

Comment: actually I checked it out already and can't find any docs about `nlp-architect.utils`, I've just started this and it's difficult to follow the tutorials without any docs on the things being used in it

Comment: There isn't explicit documentation for the `utils` package. We are updating our documentation in each release and will surely try to document those tools.